# How can I extract the "Tokens Transferred" from a BSC transaction?

Tags: binance-smart-chain, ethers.js, etherscan, bscscan

When viewing a transaction on BSCScan I see a list of tokens transferred during the transaction. For example here:

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x7d8864a3336c9d51393a3587370472194f1a2aca16aea8b287c02337c27ee1ae

I can see 4 trades executed in the transaction.

Using ethers.providers I can get the transaction details and receipt with

```
provider.getTransaction(hash)
provider.getTransactionReceipt(hash)
```

I can get the gas used, gas price and so on.

But I can't find the tokens transferred and the amounts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.